# Certificate rejected by some browsers on Android

Tags: security-certificate

I'm having an odd issue that some browsers (Brave) on my phone trust the SSL-certificate I installed:

[image: Not trusted by Brave]

while others do:

[image: Trusted by standard browser]

I am familiar with the issue that Android sometimes rejects SSL-certificates, but now it's a specific browser.

Note that the Brave browser is up-to-date and never causes any issues.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The following two URLs accessed from the failed browser case can help as a first step troubleshooting: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html  and https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/   More generally, browsers typically have their own list of trusted certificates, so what they trust or not can depend on the browser, and even its version

Comment: Browser is fine. I'm beginning to believe it's a certificate trust issue. I verified on digicert and that's the only issue it can find with the certificate. It's weird that so many browsers DO support it then.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out.

An intermediate certificate was missing. After installing this correctly, Brave no longer had any issues.

I do find it surprising that Chrome did accept it without the intermediate certificate though.

Comment: Some browsers will do the extra download (of the intermediate) if not also served up by the server, and other mobile browsers seem to have issues independently downloading the intermediate referenced in the leaf cert (and thus no complete trust chain).  I have heard anecdotally that this seems to happen on Android more-so, but I have not actually found anything backing that up.